# In Tapestry how do I check, on the client side, what the size of a list is inside another object?

Tags: tapestry

So I'm using Tapestry version 5.3.8.  I have a list of objects, we'll use Orders, and inside of each Order is a list of dates that this order has been placed.  Orders can be placed again and thus will have a history.  If there is only 1 order I don't display a dropdown.  If there is multiple reorders, I display a dropdown with the dates.  I'm trying to check using if the list is greater than 1 in order to display the drop down.  I'd like this to happen on the client side.  New to Tapestry so I apologize for the simplicity of this question.

Order Request
   List of Order Dates

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to handle on the server side using a simple t:if test around the drop down menu. However, if you really want to do it on the client (e.g., maybe the value can change after the page is rendered on the server), you have to provide the list size from the server (using some JavaScript to make an Ajax request to get the number from some server-side service). That becomes a standard JavaScript problem, not really something​ specific to Tapestry.